# WebStorm code completion - frontend (React) & backend (Deno)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webstorm, deno, react-fullstack

#### Part of files tree

```
crypto
├── backend
│   └── server.ts
└── frontend
    ├── configs
    ├── source
    ├── node_modules
    └── package.json
```

#### Questions

How to configure proper code completion for the **WebStorm** code editor if backend is based on **Deno** and frontend on **React**?

How to enable **Deno** only for backend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you cannot set different settings while opening the project root with both backend and frontend. You have to separately open each folder (backend and frontend) in webstorm and set the settings specific to the folder. At least that's how I do it in vscode.